# Why does Electron window have a border around my canvas?

Tags: css, html5-canvas, electron

Border on top and left: [image]

That red line is being drawn with:

```
Deadline.prototype.draw = function(client, context) {
    var percent = this.charge / this.maxCharge;
    context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    var w = percent * client.canvas.width;
    client.drawRect((client.canvas.width / 2) - 0.5 * w, this.y, w, 2, context.fillStyle);
}
```

and when the percentage is 100, it starts a few pixels off to the left.

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="black" style="overflow: hidden">
    <div id="game_container">
        <canvas id="canvas" style= "width: 450; height: 600;">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

From electron main.js:

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 450, height: 600,
    'title' : 'Quantum Pilot', 'transparent' : true,
    'web-preferences' : {'allow-displaying-insecure-content' : true}});
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/game.html');
```

Comment: It might be `body { margin: 8px; }`, which Chrome adds by default. Try adding reset styles for it like `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: Would that explain it coming from the top & left?

Comment: When I try <body bgcolor="black" style="overflow: hidden, margin: 0px"> , I now get scroll bars in my window, even though the canvas & window should be identical sizes

Comment: You should put a semicolon in your style definition, not a comma:
`style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0px"`, otherwise styles are not recognized correctly. I guess it is visible only from the left side because of `overflow: hidden`. But overall it is just a guess, I am not sure if it is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might get a black border if you were using with `mainWindow.setResiazble(false)`. The workaround is to `preventDefault()` the `will-resize` event.

```
// We don't need you.
// mainWindow.setResizable(false);

// Use this instead.
mainWindow.on("will-resize", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you won't update the value later, you could just add `resize: false` to `BrowserWindow`

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    // ...
    resizable: false,
});
```

[image]